# Multer Error Handling

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, error-handling, multer

According to Multer's official docs this is the correct way to handle errors within Multer.

```
var upload = multer().single('avatar')

app.post('/profile', function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      // An error occurred when uploading
      return
    }

    // Everything went fine
  })
})
```

My code is set up a little differently and I cannot figure out how I'd change my code below to handle errors in this way. My biggest problem is my var upload set up is very different in order to work with Amazon S3. How would I change my code below to incorporate the error handling as shown above?

```
var upload = multer({
    limits : { files: 3 },
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: 'mybucket',
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
            var fileExtension = file.originalname.split(".")[1];
            var path = "uploads/" + req.user._id + Date.now() + "." + fileExtension;
            cb(null, path); 
        },
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './public/uploads');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
  }
    })

});
```

My post route is set up like this... (Only part of the code shown)

```
router.post("/", upload.array('image', 3), function(req, res, next){


      var filepath = undefined;

      var filepath2 = undefined;

      var filepath3 = undefined;

    if(req.files[0]) {
        filepath = req.files[0].key;
    } 

      if(req.files[1]) {
        filepath2 = req.files[1].key;
    } 

     if(req.files[2]) {
        filepath3 = req.files[2].key;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you still have the doubt but for anyone that still looking after it you should call your function from inside using the power of closures.

So your code would be something as:

```
var upload = multer({
    limits : { files: 3 },
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: 'mybucket',
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
            var fileExtension = file.originalname.split(".")[1];
            var path = "uploads/" + req.user._id + Date.now() + "." + fileExtension;
            cb(null, path); 
        },
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './public/uploads');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
  }
    })

}).array('image', 3);

router.post("/", function(req, res, next) {

 upload(req, res, function (err) {
 //deal with the error(s)   
if (err) {
      // An error occurred when uploading
      return
    }

    // Everything went fine
// put here whatever you want to do with your code
 var filepath = undefined;

      var filepath2 = undefined;

      var filepath3 = undefined;

    if(req.files[0]) {
        filepath = req.files[0].key;
    } 

      if(req.files[1]) {
        filepath2 = req.files[1].key;
    } 

     if(req.files[2]) {
        filepath3 = req.files[2].key;
    }

  });

});
```

So in that way you can deal with your errors yourself instead of using the default handler of express.js. Hope it helped! :)